# Enumerate pc's on a workgroup using WMI (c++)

Tags: c++, wmi, enumeration, workgroup

I'm trying to enumerate all the pc's in my workgroup lan (not a domain) using WMI.

I can't figure out which class to use or if there is any class that offers this functionality?

I've tried several classes but the one that seems that should do the work (Win32_NetworkClient) does not show what i expected to...

Is this possible using WMI, or only using LDAP with a domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [Win32_ComputerSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to enumerate possibles, filter using `PartOfDomain` and `Workgroup` fields.

You may need to set up a user account on each workgroup computer that has the required privileges.  For complete info see [here](http://www.homesignals.com/home-automation/using-vbscript-and-wmi-to-interrogate-pcs-in-a-workgroup.html).

> Windows Security – We need to setup
>   the windows account we’re going to use
>   similarly across all PCs we intend to
>   remotely access. This account should
>   be in the Administrator’s group.
>
> Windows Firewall – We must be able to
>   remotely connect to a PC running
>   Windows Firewall with WMI and VB
>   Script. This will be done by
>   configuring a secure WMI connection in
>   Windows.
>
> Guest User – In a Windows XP
>   workgroup, all remote connections
>   coming from the “network” will be
>   authenticated as a Guest User. A Guest
>   User has very few rights so we must
>   determine how to configure Windows to
>   recognize the account used by the
>   remote connection.

Comment: It only returns the computer where the application call the list using Win32_ComputerSystem.
Should i use another namespace rather than ROOT\\CIMV2? or the call to ExecQuery should use any particular flag?

Comment: I would experiment with this using a GUI tool.  Perhaps the local computer is the only one that gets retrieved by default?  I will dig a bit and add info if I can find more.  WMI Admin Tools are here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=6430f853-1120-48db-8cc5-f2abdc3ed314&displaylang=en