# List all machines connected to a LAN

Tags: winapi, network-programming, wmi

Is it possible to get a list of all reachable nodes (machines connected to a LAN) through WMI ? if not then how can I get a list of all reachable nodes using other methods?

Comment: What do you mean which "reachable nodes"?

Comment: all the Computers connected in the same network. e.h. the I've my Laptop and my PC is connected with my router. now I want see that two nodes are connected. mine is 192.162.0.2 and the laptop one is. 192.168.0.4 Hope it clears.

Comment: My response here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146446/enumerate-pcs-on-a-workgroup-using-wmi-c) might work for WMI, I see OP there did not close the loop so maybe that's problematic

Answer (score 2):

As far I know the WMI  does not provide  any  method to enumerate the machines connected to a LAN. however you can use another methods like these :

1. Enumerate the windows network resources using the [`WNetOpenEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385478%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`WNetEnumResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385449%28VS.85%29.aspx) windows functions.
2. Performing a NetBios lookup using the [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) protocol, [here](http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/nbtscan.html) you can found a tool with surce code included.
3. Running multiples ping commands to scan an range of address , in this option you can use the WMI check this sample [`Making a PING with Delphi and the WMI`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/making-a-ping-with-delphi-and-the-wmi/) or you can use the [`IcmpSendEcho`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366050%28VS.85%29.aspx) Function to cunstruct your ping.
4. Also you can check the [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) which have a [Nmap API](http://nmap.org/book/nse-api.html)

Comment: NetBIOS support has been dropped in newer OSes.  Option 1. looks best to me, that's how Windows does it I think.

Comment: Even WNetEnumResource do not serve the purpose. Is there any other method to enumerate machines in network?